# What's wrong with this

Tags: counting

Here's the question: Do more baby names start with "A" or "B"? Write code to count and print those two counts ("A" count, then "B" count).

I then write this code down:

table = new SimpleTable("baby-2010.csv");

count1 = 0;

count2 = 0;

for (row: table) {

// your code here

if (row.getField("name").startsWith("A")) {

count1 = count1 + 1; }

if (row.getField("name").startsWith("B")) {

count2 = count2 + 2; }

}
print("A count:",count1)
print("B count:",count2)

I ran the code which then came out like this: A count: 258 
B count: 198

Any ideas as to why this might be wrong?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. Note, however, that you are increasing `count2` by 2 instead of by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I don't think this is the appropriate place for this question.

Second; why are you incrementing count2 by 2 each time you find a "name" field that begins with a B? Surely this should be incremented by 1, like count 1 is.

Out of interest, do you know what the correct results should be?

Could you post them?

Comment: Ah that answered it, I probably just wasn't thinking and just added two due to count1 having 1. Thanks.